# jQuery / PHP - Lazy loading gallery keeps trying to fetch images even when they've all loaded

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I've got an image gallery that is showing one image per row inside of a div. I don't want the next image to load until it reaches the edge of the viewport (to save on server resources). All the images are named sequentially in the same folder (img/1.jpeg, img/2.jpeg, img/3.jpeg, ...).

I'm using a modified jQuery plugin to do this, but it still keeps trying to fetch the next image after all the images in the directory have been loaded. **It's the last if statement I'm having trouble with here.**

How do I stop the function from running once the last image in the directory has loaded?

```
<?php 
// Count total number of images in the directory
$directory = "img/";
$totalImages = count(glob("" . $directory . "*.jpeg"));
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function(){
    scrollalert();
});
function scrollalert(){
    var scrolltop=$('#scrollbox').attr('scrollTop');
    var scrollheight=$('#scrollbox').attr('scrollHeight');
    var windowheight=$('#scrollbox').attr('clientHeight');
    if(scrolltop>=(scrollheight-(windowheight)))
    {
        // Fetch next image
        var nextImgNum=$('#content img').length + 1;
        $('#content').append('<img src=\"book1/'+nextImgNum+'.jpeg\" /><br />');
        updatestatus();
    }

    if(nextImgNum<=<?php echo $totalImages ?>)
    {
        setTimeout('scrollalert();', 0); 
    }
}

</script>
```

Any tips to optimize this script are greatly appreciated too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That script is highly inefficient and keeps the browser quite busy. You're basically in a tight loop checking whether the user has scrolled the page and avoiding the browser's script timeout via the use of setTimeout(). This is not something I would recommend. You can definitely fix this issue, but why not use the jQuery Lazy Load plug-in?

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/lazyload

Comment: That plugin doesn't work in modern browsers. The images all get loaded in the background anyway.

Comment: It looks like modern browsers queue up loading of <img src=''/> URLs as the HTML is parsed. Hence by the time the jQuery Lazy Load plugin executes, the browser is already loading (or preparing to load) them. I resolved the issue in the Lazy Load plugin by requiring lazy-loaded images to specify the URL in an <img original='URL'/>. Update can be found here: https://github.com/JamesKovacs/jquery_lazyload Even if you choose not to use the Lazy Load plugin, you should study how it accomplishes lazy loading without setTimeout(func, 0) calls.

Comment: James, do you have a working example of the lazyload plugin using *original* attributes? I tried to do it but I'm stuck on the loading image: http://s194239704.onlinehome.us/bookneto/lazyload/

Comment: Grab the code from github and drop it on a webserver (locally hosted works fine). https://github.com/JamesKovacs/jquery_lazyload/archives/master

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The lazy load plugin has a number of advantages over the code I was trying to use before (despite the non-standard HTML). I voted you up, but I'll leave the question unanswered in case someone finds a solution to the specific problem I was having.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with the lazyload plugin, it doesn't work properly with webkit.
See [Bug 6656](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6656) (this bug may also be related to your problem) and the project page for Lazyload

Answer (score 0):

Change your comparison operator from <= to <.

Comment: No dice... Firefox just loads the first image and then stops. Chrome, oddly enough, loads between 14 and 20 images all at once, then doesn't go any further than that.